# What does the “BUILD_CUDA_STUBS” option do when building OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, cmake

In open CV CMakeLists.txt, there is a flag called "BUILD_CUDA_STUBS":

```
OCV_OPTION(BUILD_CUDA_STUBS         "Build CUDA modules stubs when no CUDA SDK" OFF  IF (NOT APPLE_FRAMEWORK) )
```

What does this means? It sounds like, open cv's doc  is a bit [limited](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15967) on the build flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s poorly, or un-, documented.

If `BUILD_CUDA_STUBS` is enabled, when building, it (supposedly) adds some code (“*CUDA stubs*”) to replace the CUDA toolkit(’s drivers? IDK), to enable building CUDA-powered code on a machine that does not have the CUDA toolkit installed.

I recommend you just leave it `OFF`, which is the default, and install the genuine CUDA toolkit on your machine.